# Inversion with pronoun

Tags: grammar, pronouns, inversion

When reading novels, we often see expressions such as

> "I don't want to talk to you," said Mark in a quiet voice.

Is it okay to replace "Mark" with "he"? I argued with my English teacher about this a long time ago. She said such sentences are common but I thought it's weird. I still think "he" should come before "said". Is there a distinction between noun and pronoun in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common form would indeed be:

> "I don't want to talk to you," he said in a quiet voice.

It is possible to do the inversion with a pronoun. The main trouble with this sentence is the adverbial phrase "in a quiet voice". Since it is part of the verb phrase, it is part of the inversion too:

> "I don't want to talk to you," in a quiet voice said he.

Which way you want to write it is a stylistic choice, and I would find the above sentence rather stilted and awkward. Dropping the adverbial phrase makes it less awkward:

> "I don't want to talk to you," said he.

This sort of construction is most often found in literature, but would be very unusual in everyday speech.

Answer (score 2):

"said he" can be found in texts of past centuries; it would be considered unusual or deliberately archaic today.

Comment: It's interesting how _said Mark_ sounds so normal but _said he_ sounds so archaic.

Comment: "This is a handy cove," says he, at length; "and a pleasant sittyated grog-shop."